# Can I preload mp4 before play with MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Can I preload mp4 before play with MPMoviePlayerController ?

I have a local mp4 video. I fount it stop at the first frame little time. I'm sure it don't matter to network. Can it preload to memry before play with MPMoviePlayerController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by "local" you mean "on a machine in the same room as you".  And if that is true, then the short answer is: "Yes you can."

The way I would do this is to save (or cache) a copy of the movie file to your Documents or Cache directory on your iPhone and then when you create your `MPMoviePlayerController` object, you can refer to the file saved on the device (via a NSURL pointing to the file saved).

Take a look at Apple's documentation for [MPMoviePlayerController's `initWithContentURL:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/initWithContentURL%3a) (which I have linked for you).

If by "local" you mean the file is already on the device and it is inexplicably freezing, then there is likely another problem with the mp4 you are trying to play.